# How to make Ubuntu dynamically change audio profile?

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, hdmi, kodi

Is it possible to make Ubuntu dynamically/automatically change the output audio profile?

I have an HTPC running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 hooked up with a receiver via HDMI. I've set the audio profile to Digital Surround 5.1 in the audio settings and it works fine. But with the Raspberry Pi running OpenELEC I had before, it would change the output depending on the file I was watching. For example playing a surround movie would change the output to 5.1 and playing a YouTube video would change it to 2.0. I could see that through the display of the receiver. Now it's always in 5.1 mode. The integrated upmix of ubuntu works well, but I'd prefer to use the one of my receiver.

P.S.: I mostly use Kodi for playback, but I will be running Chrome sometimes and I will stream games through Steam in surround (atm streaming games in surround works perfectly).